# What does this personal essay prompt mean?

Tags: graduate-admissions, statement-of-purpose

I am in the middle of my application to Princeton physics graduate school. Princeton requires a personal essay, with the [prompt](https://gradschool.princeton.edu/admission-onboarding/prepare/personal-essay):

> Princeton is strongly committed to welcoming students from diverse backgrounds and experiences. Applicants are required to submit a statement with their application briefly describing how their academic interests and life experiences would help them contribute to Princeton's scholarly community.

My background is simply "I liked physics courses, got a degree and did research," and my potential contribution to the scholarly community is simply "I did good research, and I intend to do more good research."

Can someone elaborate on what exactly they are looking for here? I already discussed the details of research I have done and that I plan on doing in my statement of purpose, so I'm not sure what is to be included in the personal essay that isn't in the statement of purpose (here are the [prompts](https://phy.princeton.edu/academics/graduate-program/graduate-admissions) for the statement of purpose).

Edit: My post is substantially different from the "duplicate posts", which *directly ask for how you contribute to diversity*:

> describe any aspects of your personal background, accomplishments, or achievements that will allow the department to evaluate your contributions to the University's diversity mission

> How your perspectives or activities contribute to social or cultural diversity

> might contribute to the diversity of the graduate group

> contribute to the diverse learning community we strive to create

Princeton's prompt is ultimately asking

> how their academic interests and life experiences would help them contribute to Princeton's scholarly community

which is completely different. My question is focused on how I should address this, despite having already discussed it in the statement of purpose. I request that this question be reopened.

Comment: It's not actually completely different, it's the same thing with a different phrasing, perhaps trying to communicate more clearly that they aren't asking you to "check a box" about how you, personally, "are diverse". (this is addressed in the answers to the linked duplicates)

Comment: @BryanKrause I don't see how "academic interests and life experiences would help them contribute to Princeton's scholarly community" is asking how I intend to promote diversity. This seems to be your interpretation of it, and I would welcome this as an answer. However, I think many others will not see it how you do, and I ask you to give them a chance to disagree with your opinion (as I do).

Comment: "Princeton is strongly committed to welcoming students from diverse backgrounds and experiences."

Comment: @BryanKrause I know that it has the word "diverse" in the prompt, and yet I still find that their prompt *literally* doesn't ask for this. How can I appeal my case to someone else?

Comment: I guess I'll just reopen it, but we don't need a new question about the infinite possible ways to interpret every phrasing of this sort of question. Unfortunately reopening it removes all the helpful links for the next person that finds this particular version.

Answer (score 1):

Contribution to the community is never "simply" doing good research. You could describe, for example, how your experience and background could bring in new perspectives. Remember, there are tons of smart people who can do good research. It is barely the minimum requirement, especially when you are applying for top universities. Try to convey in your application how you are not yet another regular smart student.

Comment: Cam you clarify what you mean by "new perspectives"? I guess I can say that my background has fostered an "I'll believe it when it's proven" mentality,  and that this mentality fosters new ideas in research...is this along the lines of what you meant?

Comment: That could be one example, say, how you built up such mentality, how it helped/challenged you in past experiences, how it would help you in the future, and fit into or add value to the place you're applying... Just an example since, at the end, you should know best about your strength and positionality (that's why it's called personal essay).

Answer (score 1):

You're overthinking it. They don't want to hear about your research, you already talked about that in your statement of purpose. They want to learn about *you*. An essay like this (annoying as it may be to write) is a chance for you to sell yourself and show your personality. What about *your* experiences and interests make you a worthwhile addition to the program? How can *you* contribute to the university? Why should they choose *you* over the countless other well-qualified individuals?

The ways to answer those questions are infinite and obviously specific to you. There is no "right" answer to the prompt - no tricks or test there.

My advice would be to reflect on your life and experiences. Sometimes it helps to just start writing - the first draft doesn't have to be perfect. Come up with an answer, sleep on it, then revisit it with fresh eyes.